# Using modal alert panel from modal session

Tags: cocoa, nsalert, modal-window

I'm having troubles using a `NSAlert` panel when I am already inside a modal window. What happens is that when the alert panel is closed also the parent modal session is terminated.

The modal window is performed using `NSModalSession` in the usual way

```
modal_session = [NSApp beginModalSessionForWindow:modalwindow];

for (;;) {
    if ([NSApp runModalSession:modal_session] != NSModalResponseContinue)
            break;
    // do some work...
}
[NSApp endModalSession:modal_session];
```

while the alert panel is run using `[myAlertPanel runModal]`

Cocoa documentation does not deem this situation as improper, on the contrary it seems to state that this should be perfectly possible.

Any suggestion?